# Sum one field in one table and display the result from both in the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I have two tables. One with posts and one with votes. Both tables contain postId (PK/FK). I want to group all posts inte Vote table and sum the postVote for each post. Then in the view I want do display the post and the total vote for each post. If there is no vote on that postId I want do use 0 as default.

Ex if I have this data in the post table

```
+--------+---------+-------------+---------+
| PostId | Message | MessageDate | User_Id |
+--------+---------+-------------+---------+
| 1      | test 1  | 2016-01-01  | 1       |
+--------+---------+-------------+---------+
| 2      | test 2  | 2016-01-01  | 1       |
+--------+---------+-------------+---------+
| 3      | test 3  | 2016-01-01  | 1       |
+--------+---------+-------------+---------+
```

Votes table

```
+--------+------------+---------+
| PostId | PostVote   | User_Id |
+--------+------------+---------+
| 1      | 1          | 1       |
+--------+------------+---------+
| 1      | 1          | 2       |
+--------+------------+---------+
| 2      | -1         | 1       |
+--------+------------+---------+
```

I want to display this in the view

```
Message  Vote
Test 1 -  2
Test 2 -  -1
Test 3 -  0
```

Since two users voted 1 (1+1) on postId, one user voted -1 on postId 2 and there is no votes on PostId 3 (therefore should it be default 0 in the view).

This is my post model

```
public class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
        this.Vote = new HashSet<Vote>();
    }

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime MessageDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Vote> Vote { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Vote model

```
public class Vote
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public int PostVote { get; set; }
}
```

I guess I should use a Viewmodel and created this

```
public class ListPostsViewModel
{
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public List<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
}
```

I'am then trying to use my ViewModel in the controller, sum the votes based on postId and merge the posts and votes to the view. This is my controller right now.

```
var posts = db.Posts.OrderByDescending(p => p.PostId).ToList();

var postsVM = posts.Select(post => new ListPostsViewModel { Posts = posts});

var votes = db.Votes.GroupBy(u => u.PostId)
                .Select(v =>
                                new
                                {
                                    PostId = v.Key,
                                    TotalVotes = v.Sum(w => w.PostVote) //sum the votes
                                }).ToList();

var votesVM = posts.Select(post => new ListPostsViewModel { Votes = votes });
```

And I get this error on votesVM

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<FreePost.Models.Vote>'

Comment: Your query is creating a collection of anonymous objects. You need to project the query into the model you using - `.Select(v => new SomeModel { PostId = v.Key, ...` But your current `Vote` class does not have a property for `TotalVotes` so you need a new model. And its unclear how your `ListPostsViewModel` would be able to generate that view - you model would need to be a collection of a model with properties `string Message` and `int TotalVotes`

Comment: You need a single query with a join (on the `PostId` field) and select the `Message` field from the `Post` table and the sum of the `PostVote` fiels from the `Votes` table.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Need some sleep, but if you have not worked it out, will add an answer in the morning

Comment: I guess my controller (and viewmodel) are wrong. I don't want to have a property for TotalVotes, it is a calculated value from the votes to the view and nothing I save in the database. TotalVotes are the sum of all votes with the same PostId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is caused because your `var votes = ...` query is generating a collection of anonymous objects which you then attempt to assign to a property which is `List<Vote>` (they are not the same type).

In order to generate the view you want, your view model needs to be

```
public class PostVoteVM
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int TotalVotes { get; set; }
}
```

so that in the view you can use

```
@model IEnumerable<PostVoteVM>
<table>
    @foreach(var post in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@post.Message</td>
            <td>@post.TotalVotes </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Sine your models have the correct navigation properties, you only need one query, and project the results of the query into a collection of the view model

```
var model = db.Posts.Include(p => p.Vote) // Include may not be required
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.PostId)
    .Select(p => new PostVoteVM()
    {
        Message = p.Message,
        TotalVotes = p.Vote.Sum(v => v.PostVote)
    });
return View(model);
```